# Like "relinquish" but less extreme

Tags: business-language

What alternatives are there for relinquish or abdicate in a business setting?

For example:

> Business X is willing to [relinquish] their preexisting partnership for this opportunity.

Comment: I don't get this one. In what sense is "relinquish" extreme? Also I don't think partnerships are normally *relinquished* - they're normally *dissolved* or perhaps *abandonned*.

Comment: Did you find any possibilities in a thesaurus?

Answer (score 10):

How about ["cede"](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=cede)?

> Business X is willing to cede their preexisting partnership for this opportunity.

Or "abandon"?

> Business X is willing to abandon their preexisting partnership for this opportunity.

Or keep it simple: "end"

> Business X is willing to end their preexisting partnership for this opportunity.

I'm guessing that if you want words that are less extreme than "relinquish", words like "terminate" and "abort" are probably not good choices.

You could also go with word like "nullify" or "cancel". I'm not sure they carry the meaning you want in this context, but they might work.